# Website appears with wrong permalink in Google's search

Tags: permalinks

Whenever I try to google my website (nobletuning) in google search, it appears, everything is fine. But it appears with /en permalink which is not enabled in anyway. With this permalink the website is missing some of important parts and it is not translated correctly. I've tried changing the permalink structure and dont have any more ideas on how to fix this.
Any help?
p.s it doesn't happen with microsoft edge browser.

Comment: "p.s it doesn't happen with microsoft edge browser." - you mean in Bing search not Google?

Comment: Do you have a Google Search Console for the site? I don't know if there's anything in there you can use to pick the site's main link. Do you have an XML sitemap, and is Google crawling it?